# Dreamweaver CS6 view includes

Tags: php, javascript, css, dreamweaver

I recently switched to dreamweaver version CS6 from CS4. In CS4 there was a handy feature that would show tabs of the includes files. CSS PHP Javascript etc. It would show these tabs right above the "code, split, design, live". Does CS6 not have this feature or do I simply have to enable it?

If so, where and how?

Oh yeah. I'm using the Design Compact dreamweaver layout.

Hope you guys can help me out. I really need that feature back ^^

Answer (score 2):

Nvm. I finally found what I had to change. In the general settings, enable relative files: on.

Answer (score 1):

It's not only there but it works better than it did before because it can scan deeper for PHP files (I think CS5.5 improved it for use with things like Wordpress). When you open a file with includes they should be there next to the file name. Although it's better, it's still not perfect so if you have dynamically created includes you still might not see them.

Comment: Dumb question but are you sure you have a file with includes? Here's a cs6 screenshot (kinda small) where you can see the includes are where you said, above the "Code/Split/Design" buttons: http://media.creativebloq.futurecdn.net/sites/creativebloq.com/files/images/2012/04/dreamweaver2.jpg